# Displaying Pickers on Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the pickers in order the users to be able to select the hour. I create one FragmentActivity with the corresponding android XML. The FragmentActivity is the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TimePickerFragment tpf = new TimePickerFragment();
    tpf.getFragmentManager();

}


public static class TimePickerFragment  extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
 int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

 return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour,minute,DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

 public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
   // Do something with the time chosen by the user 
 }

 public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
   DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment ();
   newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
 }

}
}
```

The XML is the following:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <Button 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello_world" 
   android:onClick="TimePickerFragment " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code was retrieved from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Now, the problem is that I'm not able to see the pickers with the date. It just display a white screen. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. the only change that I have done, id that I use the  getFragmentManager() instead of the getSupportFragmentManager(). And this why,when I'm using the last one is hitting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `android:onClick` attribute isn't correct. Your xml should be:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
        android:text="Pick Time" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`showTimePickerDialog` will now be called when the user clicks the `Button`. This method should be in `MainActivity`.

Also, you need to set the layout to be used by calling `setContentView`. `MainActivity` looks like this (I haven't included `TimePickerFragment`):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }
    public static class TimePickerFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: This code isn't compatible with versions of Android below 3.0. For that you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` and the support package. See http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#SettingUp

Comment: when i use the getSupportFragmentManager method i receive an error which says: Multiple markers at this line - The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)

Comment: I've edited my answer to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Import classes from the support package whenever possible (`DialogFragment`, `FragmentActivity`).

Answer (score 2):

`FragmentActivity` is part of the support library, so when you extend that, as you have, you must use `getSupportFragmentManager()`.  If you get an error when you do that, then post the error.

Comment: when i use the getSupportFragmentManager method i receive an error which says:                                                                   Multiple markers at this line
 - The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the 
  arguments (FragmentManager, String)

Comment: In that case you're not using the support package version of `DialogFragment`.  Make sure every `Fragment` that you use is either from the support package, or not (API 11+).  You can't mix them.